# How animate awesome font in angular on hover

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I need to know how can I scale icon on hover. Normally I used this sass code:

```
.social
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8)
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8)
  -o-transform: scale(0.8)
  &:hover
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1)
    -o-transform: scale(1.1)
```

It stopped work when I start to use standard awesome-font lib for Angular. My code:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/#/">
  <fa-icon id="social-fb"
           class="social"
           [icon]="['fab','facebook-square']"
           size="3x">
  </fa-icon>
</a>
```

I'm new in Angular. If this question is stupid, I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since fa-icon is a component it does not apply scaling as it would with a raw svg.

What you need to do is access the child element in the fa-icon component. Try to access the child svg element - (I am remembering that the child is a svg element, but use your inspect tools to find out exactly)

```
&:hover {
    > svg {
      transform: scale(1.1)
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1)
      -o-transform: scale(1.1)
    }
}
```

Remember the default `transform: scale(1.1)`, it is supported by most modern browsers.

Comment: It's doesn't work. In inspect mode in the browser I see that icons don't have any hover.

Comment: you put the &:hover in the parent og the icon. The important thing is that the css hits the svg element.